# Is there a better way to prepend a glyphicon to Laravel's BootForm plugin buttons?

Tags: laravel

I'm using the [BootForm](https://packagist.org/packages/adamwathan/bootforms) plugin to manage my forms in Laravel.

It's very neat, but as it automates a lots of things, there are a few ones that aren't possible anymore.

For example, I'm trying to add a glyphicon to one of my buttons. I don't know if there is a better way to do it, but here's what I've done so far :

```
    {!!
        BootForm::submit('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" aria-hidden="true"></span> '.trans('forms.disconnect.submit_button'))
            ->class('btn btn-danger')
    !!}
```

[image: The rendered button]

Do you see a better way to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a fan of just doing it by attaching to the classes. Here's an example:

Let the btn's know that the `:before` property should be using the `Glyphicons Halflings` class:

```
.btn-glyphed {
    padding-left: 2.5rem;
    position: relative;
}

.btn-glyphed:before {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    position: absolute;
    left: 1rem;
}
```

Then just attach the glyphicon directly to the btn class:

```
->class('btn btn-danger btn-glyphed glyphicon-log-out');
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great ! How come I never found it on Bootstrap's documentation ?

Comment: @MarcBrillault It's kind of hacky, but I enjoy it personally.

Comment: Well, it seems I'm going to enjoy it myself!